# Python: How to completely remove an object

Tags: python, objects

How can I completely remove an object (for example a camera) using python scripting?

Using something like:

```
scene.objects.unlink(camera)
```

Does not work, since it is still available in **bpy.data.objects**. However, using:

```
bpy.data.objects.remove(camera)
```

still doesn't remove the camera, since it continues to exists in **bpy.data.cameras**.

Is there a way to remove an object from all of these places at the same time?

Comment: `camera` is actually an object datablock, not a camera. You need to unlink the object from the scene, delete the camera (`ob.data`, which would be `camera.data` in your example) and finally delete the object. If not possible to remove datablocks if they have users however, and clearing the user count may lead to crashes later on - thus it's advisable to use the delete operator instead.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can use [`bpy.ops.object.delete()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.object.html?highlight=delete#bpy.ops.object.delete) operator to **remove selected objects**:

```
import bpy

# Deselect all
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

# Select the object
bpy.data.objects['Camera'].select = True    # Blender 2.7x

# https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Python_API/Scene_and_Object_API
bpy.data.objects['Camera'].select_set(True) # Blender 2.8x
    
bpy.ops.object.delete()
```

---

In order to remove **multiple objects**, you can iterate through all objects, set the [`select`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.select) state in Blender 2.7x or call [`select_set(state)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/master/bpy.types.Object.html?highlight=select_set#bpy.types.Object.select_set) in Blender 2.8x based on a certain condition and *finally* call the operator *one* time.

**Blender 2.7x**

```
import bpy

# Delect objects by type
for o in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    if o.type == 'MESH':
        o.select = True
    else:
        o.select = False

# Call the operator only once
bpy.ops.object.delete()

# Save and re-open the file to clean up the data blocks
bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile(filepath=bpy.data.filepath)
bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath=bpy.data.filepath)
```

**Blender 2.8x**

```
import bpy

# Select objects by type
for o in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    if o.type == 'MESH':
        o.select_set(True)
    else:
        o.select_set(False)

# Call the operator only once
bpy.ops.object.delete()

# Save and re-open the file to clean up the data blocks
bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile(filepath=bpy.data.filepath)
bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath=bpy.data.filepath)
```

---

**Context override (2.7x & 2.8x)**

Instead of (de)selecting the object(s) beforehand, you can also pass a *custom context* (a list of objects in this case) to avoid changing the selection within the viewport:

```
import bpy

objs = [bpy.context.scene.objects['Camera'], bpy.context.scene.objects['Cube']]
bpy.ops.object.delete({"selected_objects": objs})
```

Example on how to remove objects by certain *types*:

```
import bpy

objs = [ob for ob in bpy.context.scene.objects if ob.type in ('CAMERA', 'MESH')]
bpy.ops.object.delete({"selected_objects": objs})
```

Further reading: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.html#overriding-context

---

**Context override (3.2x)**

The previous methodology has been deprecated and a dedicated context manager *context.temp_override* has been added to the Python API:

```
import bpy

objs = [bpy.context.scene.objects['Camera'], bpy.context.scene.objects['Cube']]
with bpy.context.temp_override(selected_objects=objs):
    bpy.ops.object.delete()
```

Further reading:
https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/3.2/Python_API
https://docs.blender.org/api/3.2/bpy.types.Context.html#bpy.types.Context.temp_override

Comment: Doesn't work, the camera is still available in bpy.data.cameras

Comment: Ah, good to know, then thats the information I was missing!

Comment: if before that you had selected some other object, it will also be selected and then removed...

Comment: @ntg Yep, that's the nature of the *operator* and also mentioned in the answer `...remove selected objects`. What's your question? How to avoid that behavior?

Comment: @poor: No question, just an observation.... Running bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')  beforehand will deselect everything, "avoiding" it.

Comment: @ntg You can set the objects [`select` flag](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Object.html?highlight=select#bpy.types.Object.select) to `False` for certain objects in the scene/context. For **more control** go with a `for` loop instead (`for ob in bpy.data.objects: ob.select = False`), which does basically the same as the *operator*, but allows for instance to exclude objects in order to "avoid" re-selecting ;)

Comment: It doesn't seem to work if the object is on another layer.

Comment: @p2or I have some memory leakage issues. While searching, I came across your answer. I wonder, are there better ways (after about two years) to solve memory leakage issues and removing left-out data blocks? Could you please take a look at my question [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102025/how-to-prevent-memory-leakage-in-blender)? I hope you can offer a solution besides saving/opening blender file. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @JanRüegg I found a very easy solution to the problem :) I updated my answer in this question too

Comment: Worth noting some objects in `bpy.data.objects` will never have context (not in `context.selected_objects`), eg if not a member of the context scene,  will not be removed even when select attribute is set to true when using the delete operator.

Comment: FYI I am using Blender 2.8b and `Object` no longer seems to have the `select` attribute on it.

Comment: @TomášHübelbauer Updated the Answer for 2.8x.

Comment: Isn't `use_global` parameter for such cases? @batFINGER

Comment: 2.8 full copy scene, to test run script `RuntimeError: Error: Object 'Camera' not in View Layer 'RenderLayer`  On the global flag, am of the understanding that it will remove same object from all scenes that it is linked to. Wont delete other objects in other scene or from data if not linked to context scene.

Comment: Yeah right, same here @batFINGER. Thanks for testing, I'll check whether there is some bizarre workaround or mention that.

Comment: Suggest iterate over scene objects, not `bpy.data.objects`

Comment: Thanks, iterating over scene objects now :) @batFINGER

Answer (score 86):

This can be done without using `ops` which makes it *much* faster then using the `ops` call.

Buried deep in the documentation is the [remove](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.BlendDataObjects.html#bpy.types.BlendDataObjects.remove) function.

```
import bpy
objs = bpy.data.objects
objs.remove(objs["Cube"], do_unlink=True)
```

The first parameter of the `remove` function is the object to remove (in this case the default "Cube"), the second is a boolean about first unlinking the object.
If you run `objs.remove(objs["Cube"])` with the cube sitting in your 3D view you will get an error:

> RuntimeError: Error: Object 'Cube' must have zero users to be removed, found 1 (try with do_unlink=True parameter)

See this remove function only deletes data with no users. That is why you have to explicitly tell it to first unlink the object then delete it.

Comment: note that this will work in 2.77 and higher only. prior vers have no do_unlink. :-/

Comment: Note that the documentation and behaviour now have `do_unlink=True` as the default, making it unnecessary to explicitly specify it.

Answer (score 12):

You can do this:

```
item='CAMERA'
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
bpy.ops.object.select_by_type(type=item)
bpy.ops.object.delete()
```

where `item` can take any of the following values according to [this documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Object.html):

```
[‘MESH’, ‘CURVE’, ‘SURFACE’, ‘META’, ‘FONT’, ‘ARMATURE’, ‘LATTICE’, ‘EMPTY’, ‘CAMERA’, ‘LAMP’, ‘SPEAKER’]
```

The above method works, but is not ideal. The following method works and is ideal. First remove the meshes with the following code:

```
for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
     if obj.type == 'MESH':
         obj.select = True
     else:
         obj.select = False
 bpy.ops.object.delete()
```

Then you can execute the following code snippet to remove all the unused blocks. This way you **don't** have to close/open Blender or save/open a *.blend* file:

```
for block in bpy.data.meshes:
    if block.users == 0:
        bpy.data.meshes.remove(block)

for block in bpy.data.materials:
    if block.users == 0:
        bpy.data.materials.remove(block)

for block in bpy.data.textures:
    if block.users == 0:
        bpy.data.textures.remove(block)

for block in bpy.data.images:
    if block.users == 0:
        bpy.data.images.remove(block)
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE**: It looks like that there is some dependencies between some data blocks such as mesh, texture, image and materials. If you do not remove the data blocks on the highest level of the hierarchy, you **will not** be able to remove other data blocks or you have to take the risk and remove data blocks with `users` more than `0`. So make sure you use the code above in the following order to remove data blocks. This way you can remove all unlinked (`users == 0`) data blocks:

**remove meshes --> remove materials --> remove textures --> remove images**

The followings also have data blocks:

```
bpy.data.curves
bpy.data.lamps
bpy.data.cameras
```

Comment: [This](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102025/how-to-prevent-memory-leakage-in-blender) is more relevant for preventing memory leakage in Blender

Answer (score 8):

Just to add up to the great answer above, one must be in `OBJECT` mode in order to delete objects. In order to do so in Python use the following code:

```
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
```

It also makes sense to return to previous mode, after the operation:

```
oldMode = bpy.context.mode
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
 ...Select your object here
bpy.ops.object.delete()
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode=oldMode)
```

Answer (score 1):

To empty an entire scene, I typically include these lines at the start immediately after import bpy

```
    removeThese = bpy.context.copy()
    removeThese['selected_objects'] = list(bpy.context.scene.objects)
    bpy.ops.object.delete(removeThese)
```