# Python Scripting: Remove Curve Object

Tags: python, scripting

Preferably not using selection, tried `bpy.data.meshes.remove` don't works for it

Comment: not a duplicate, simply using `bpy.ops.delete` will not remove the Curve data, until save and reopen, but my code below will.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27234/python-how-to-completely-remove-an-object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this,

- First remove the *Object* that uses the *Curve*
- Then remove the *Curve* data

code:

```
curves = bpy.data.curves
objects = bpy.data.objects
scene = bpy.context.scene

# remove the object
obj = bpy.data.objects[object_name]
cu = obj.data  # the curve
scene.objects.unlink(obj)
objects.remove(obj)

# remove the associated curve, if you need to and it doesn't have other users. 
curves.remove(cu)
```

You won't be able to remove *Curve* data if there are remaining *Objects* associated with that *Curve* data. `cu.users` will tell you how many users the *Curve* has, if that returns `0`, the curve data can be removed with no other steps, but if it's more than `0` then other *Objects* are referencing the curve and you need to clear those references first.