# How to delete unused meshes from the Outliner?

Tags: mesh

As you see on the screenshot I have many meshes in the DataBlock view of the Outliner, but in fact, I use only 3.

How to delete rest of them ?

[image]

Here is video describing the problem:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RM9Rr1gnL5g

Comment: If you save the file and open it again, will it be removed?

Comment: After several savings and openings the file (and viewing the list of meshes in Object Tab), yes, but I assume there must be a better way then just reloading project hoping that this time it will helps...

Comment: Unfortunately not, but you could use python: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32349/python-scripting-remove-curve-object?lq=1

Comment: I usually press File>Revert instead of closing and re-opening, you have save your file first of course

Answer (score 7):

Change the outliner view mode to "Orphan Data" instead of "Datablocks".
To the right of the search field in the header is a "Purge All" button;
[image]
and may simplify your problem.

This button essentially performs the save and reload process in one click, which in turn invokes Blenders garbage collection routines.

Comment: Well... In Orphan Data I see here only "brushes". And of course pressing "Purge All" button doesn't help.