# Delete Action from List

Tags: animation

I would like to remove the actions that I do not need, every time I rename an action it multiplies into something else like  0 meteactionjargon. I have a list of actions that I do not need, and I wont to remove them from the list[image]

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but try checking the outliner and changing the view mode to 'Orphan data' then untick any ticked armatures that you want to clear? ...http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33451/how-to-delete-unused-meshes-from-the-outliner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the ***Outliner*** window and type ***animation*** in the search window. Choose the object that has the action you want to delete, hover the cursor over *Animation* block and press <kbd>RMB</kbd>-->*Clear Animation Data*. Save your file. When you close and reopen it the action'll be no longer there.
[image]

Comment: It worked, but deleted everything, wanted to keep 1, although it was experimental 2 key frames :) thx

Comment: You didn't need to delete everything. I've shown you just an example ;P. Next time delete only the one you want :).