# How do I delete unused data?

Tags: blend-files, memory-management, data-blocks

I want to quickly minimize the size of a Blender file.

How do I delete any data that is not being used?

Comment: You can try the *Purge All* button: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/33459/31447

Answer (score 6):

If you're talking about materials or textures:

In the *Node* Editor, all the materials that have a "0 something" name are **materials that have no user**, it means that they are not used by any object and that they will automatically be deleted when you'll close the file.

You can delete them for good immediately if you go to the *Outliner* panel, select *Orphan Data* in the dropdown menu, then select all the materials displayed in the *materials* category and <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> > *Delete*. Or click on the *Purge* button on the top bar.

You can also do a *File > Clean Up > Unused Data-Blocks*.

To delete **materials that have users**:

If you already know by their name the materials and images you want to delete you can directly go to the *Outliner* then select *Blender File* in the dropdown menu, find your materials and images in their respective categories, and <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> *Delete* all the unwanted materials and their images.

But if you don't know their names, select them one by one in the Node editor, hold <kbd>shift</kbd> while clicking on the "X" button on the right of the material name. Now they will have a "0" displayed in front of their name, so again, they will be deleted when you'll close the file, or you can delete them right away in the *Outliner*.

After deleting materials, if some images (those that have been used by some materials) are also displayed in the *Outliner* > *Orphan Data* > *image* category, again, select them all and <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> > *Delete*.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is a based on using Blender's Python API. There is a couple of ways. First, you can reset everything to factory settings by the following:

```
bpy.ops.wm.read_factory_settings(use_empty=True)
```

Or you can simply store the current *.blend* file and re-open it as follow. First save the *.blend* file:

```
bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile(filepath=savePath) # savePath contains something like `/blendFilesOnDisk/myBlend.blend
```

And then re-open it using:

```
bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath=savePath)
```

However, if you want to keep your current settings or you do not want to reload the *.blend* file you can instead remove the unneeded data blocks manually. For instance, after you remove the meshes/objects in your scene you can execute the following code to remove all the unused data blocks that were assigned to those meshes/objects:

```
for block in bpy.data.meshes:
    if block.users == 0:
        bpy.data.meshes.remove(block)

for block in bpy.data.materials:
    if block.users == 0:
        bpy.data.materials.remove(block)

for block in bpy.data.textures:
    if block.users == 0:
        bpy.data.textures.remove(block)

for block in bpy.data.images:
    if block.users == 0:
        bpy.data.images.remove(block)
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE**: It looks like that there is some dependencies between some data blocks such as mesh, texture, image and materials. If you do not remove the data blocks on the highest level of the hierarchy, you **will not** be able to remove other data blocks or you have to take the risk and remove data blocks with `users` more than `0`. So make sure you use the code above in the following order to remove data blocks. This way you can remove all unlinked (`users == 0`) data blocks. So make sure you follow the order to remove the data blocks:

**meshes --> materials --> textures --> images**

The followings also have data blocks that you can remove but they typically do not take that much space:

```
bpy.data.curves # for curves
bpy.data.lamps # for lamps
bpy.data.cameras # for cameras
```