# Blender file size increses drastically after joning duplicated object and performs very slow

Tags: objects, blend-files, performance

When i join (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>) duplicated (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>)  multiple object or mesh then blender performs very slow and file size increases too from 100mb to 1gb. Does anyone have solutions for this issue?

Comment: You may have to share the file for some of us to diagnose what's going on. Your description is limited and it's hard to say why you are having issue, since you could have done many things - you personally aren't aware - to the file that causes that issue. How big is the mesh to begin with and how many times did you actually copy the object. Try Alt+J to minimise memory waste. The devils are in the details not just a few words they never show themselves.

Comment: @Amir kbd formatting should be per key, e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>

Comment: @Mahesh Take a look at [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102025/how-to-prevent-memory-leakage-in-blender) and [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/121534/29301) as they might be helpful. Do these before saving the *.blend* file.