# Delete meshes - context error

Tags: python, scripting

I try to delete all meshes I made by putting together about all I could find [from this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27234/python-how-to-completely-remove-an-object/75439#75439) , using this code:

```
def delete_things(spec_type):
        oldMode = bpy.context.mode
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
        for o in bpy.data.objects:
            if o.type == spec_type:
                o.select = True
            else:
                o.select = False
        bpy.ops.object.delete()
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode=oldMode)
        bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile(filepath=bpy.data.filepath)
        bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath=bpy.data.filepath)

def delete_all_mesh():
    delete_things('MESH')

delete_all_mesh()
```

I thought I made sure to set the right mode, still I get the error " `bpy.ops.object.mode_set.poll()` failed, context is incorrect"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are receiving is due to the fact your trying to change the object mode when no objects exist, because you've deleted them all.