# Deleting temporary mesh after extracting data

Tags: python

When extracting data via temporary mesh, like this:

```
mesh = object.to_mesh(bpy.context.scene, apply_modifiers=True, settings='RENDER')
```

Do I need to delete this mesh, after I'm done extracting data? Will it stay in memory after running the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**, you need to deleted them by yourself.

If you print that `mesh` object in script multiple times, you will find out that the name change by adding post-fix serial number to its based name as follow:

```
<bpy_struct, Mesh("Suzanne.002")>
<bpy_struct, Mesh("Suzanne.003")>
<bpy_struct, Mesh("Suzanne.004")>
```

And if you are using Blender 2.8, in the **Outliner Panel**, you can change display type from **View Layer** to **Orphan Data** (what an adorable name), the meshes you created will stay at there. You can **pin** them by pressing the cross button, making a fake user to let Blender keep the data-block.

[image: Orphan data create by object-to_mesh]

If you need to delete it in script, you cannot `del mesh` since the object data-block was already binded in to `bpy.data.meshes`, use `bpy.data.meshes.remove(mesh)` instead to delete it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So what is the best way to delete this mesh when I'm done with it? Also reloading the file removes the orphan meshes right?

Comment: @LennyWhite https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27234/python-how-to-completely-remove-an-object/27235

Comment: That post shows how to delete an object, I need to delete the mesh. I tried this, and it seems to work `bpy.data.meshes.remove(mesh)`.

Comment: The last voted answer show how to make it. The data was references in `bpy.data.meshes`, use the method `remove()` to delete it. `bpy.data.meshes.remove(the_suzanne)`