# Script keeps deleting all objects

Tags: python, objects

So i am not sure what happened here, but the story Is that I finished my script and it was working fine in UI and now I am running it using --background but something is broken now with deleting objects?

Using version 2.9 btw

script:

```
 print(objectsToDelete)

      for objectToDelete in objectsToDelete:        
        try:
            if objectToDelete.type == 'MESH':
                bpy.data.objects[objectToDelete.name].select_set(True)
                bpy.ops.object.delete()
        except: 
            print("")
```

output:

```
[bpy.data.objects['TR5_49'], bpy.data.objects['TR5_50'], bpy.data.objects['TR5_51'], bpy.data.objects['TR5_52'], bpy.data.objects['TR5_53'], bpy.data.objects['TR5_54'], bpy.data.objects['TR5_55'], bpy.data.objects['TR5_56'], bpy.data.objects['TR5_57'], bpy.data.objects['TR5_58'], bpy.data.objects['TR5_59'], bpy.data.objects['TR5_73'], bpy.data.objects['TR5_74'], bpy.data.objects['TR5_75'], bpy.data.objects['TR5_76'], bpy.data.objects['TR5_77'], bpy.data.objects['TR5_78'], bpy.data.objects['TR5_79'], bpy.data.objects['TR5_80'], bpy.data.objects['TR5_81'], bpy.data.objects['TR5_82'], bpy.data.objects['TR5_83'], bpy.data.objects['TR5_61'], bpy.data.objects['TR5_62'], bpy.data.objects['TR5_63'], bpy.data.objects['TR5_64'], bpy.data.objects['TR5_65'], bpy.data.objects['TR5_66'], bpy.data.objects['TR5_67'], bpy.data.objects['TR5_68'], bpy.data.objects['TR5_69'], bpy.data.objects['TR5_70'], bpy.data.objects['TR5_71'], bpy.data.objects['TR5_85'], bpy.data.objects['TR5_86'], bpy.data.objects['TR5_87'], bpy.data.objects['TR5_88'], bpy.data.objects['TR5_89'], bpy.data.objects['TR5_90'], bpy.data.objects['TR5_91'], bpy.data.objects['TR5_92'], bpy.data.objects['TR5_93'], bpy.data.objects['TR5_94'], bpy.data.objects['TR5_95']]
Info: Deleted 221 object(s)
```

Then it just goes ahead and deletes all objects in the scene!?

Length of the array is 44, so is this supposed to work differently when using --background? It's also doing this in the GUI now... which is really weird...

EDIT - Ehm, checking the selected objects crashes the program...

script:

```
if len(objectsToDelete) == len(bpy.context.selected_objects):
        print("all objects selected")
        bpy.ops.object.delete()
```

output:

```
Error   : EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
Address : 0x00007FF67F5AAC78
Module  : blender.exe
Thread  : 00000c40
Writing: C:\Users\Recreate\AppData\Local\Temp\blender.crash.txt
```

Weird all of these seem to crash for me now...

```
bpy.data.objects.remove(objectToDelete)
#bpy.data.meshes.remove(objectToDelete.data)
#bpy.data.objects[objectToDelete.name].select_set(True)
```

Comment: Using an operator to remove objects is a horrible way to do it... and looping it over and over in an try clause even more-so.  The operator deletes all selected objects. Instead  Use `bpy.data.objects.remove(ob_to_delete)`  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27234/python-how-to-completely-remove-an-object?rq=1

Comment: Alright my bad it is now crashing on some other line further below, bpy.data.objects.remove(objectToDelete) does appear to work.

Comment: Please post your full script not just snippets. If it crashes you're likely doing something that is not permitted by the Python API see the [Gotchas](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_gotcha.html#help-my-script-crashes-blender) page of the API docs.

Comment: Often wonder why if running in bg mode don't simply save a blend with those objects deleted.  Another thing if you know an object via reference as for example `ob` then using `bpy.data.objects[ob.name]` is  longwindedly getting a reference to `ob` which you have in the first place.

Comment: ... re posting full script, at the very least a minimal runable example.  One of those gotchas is often keeping a reference to an object since removed. Recommend make a list of objects to remove that contains only obs to remove and `while(remove_list): bpy.data.objects.remove(remove_list.pop())` which will ensure list no longer contains ref to deleted object.